# Xamarin Android Google Maps App map is blank and no error

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

I'm working on a Monodroid android app.  I've added Google maps with a fragment but the map will not show up and I'm not getting any errors thrown.

My Axml code :

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Activity Code :

```
    protected async override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();


        tblLocations location = Nav.GetAndRemoveParameter<tblLocations>(Intent);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
        CameraPosition.Builder builder = CameraPosition.InvokeBuilder();
        builder.Target(latLng);
        builder.Zoom(5);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = builder.Build();
        CameraUpdate cUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(cameraPosition);

        mapFrag = (MapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);
        map = mapFrag.Map;
        if (map != null)
        {
            map.MoveCamera(cUpdate);
        }
    }
```

I realize it's something with the API key but what am I missing here?

LOG CAT OUTPUT

```
    04-01 16:40:24.662 D/ChimeraFileApk(20730): Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
    04-01 16:40:24.730 E/NEW_BHD (20811): Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
    04-01 16:40:24.730 E/NEW_BHD (20811): Cannot run on production devices!
    04-01 16:40:24.755 I/Google Maps Android API(20730): Google Play services client version: 848700004-01 16:40:24.755 I/Google Maps Android API(20730): Google Play services client version: 8487000
    04-01 16:40:24.764 I/Google Maps Android API(20730): Google Play services package version: 8703436
    04-01 16:40:24.804 I/art     (20530): CollectorTransition marksweep + semispace GC freed 471(-32KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 7MB/9MB, paused 16.348ms total 16.348ms
    04-01 16:40:25.088 D/VoldConnector( 2225): SND -> {10 volume mkdirs /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/asked.askeduniversalremote/cache/}
    04-01 16:40:25.220 D/Mono    (20730): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps[0xb9b18688] -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement[0xb9b148d0]: 2
    04-01 16:40:25.283 I/b       (20730): Sending API token request.
    04-01 16:40:25.316 I/Keyboard.Facilitator( 3831): onFinishInput()
    04-01 16:40:25.357 I/LaunchCheckinHandler( 2225): Displayed asked.askeduniversalremote/md5d1d3b2ca018abe66d5a9f8b4db614c6f.ViewOtherLocationOnMapActivity,wp,ca,947
    04-01 16:40:25.357 I/ActivityManager( 2225): Displayed asked.askeduniversalremote/md5d1d3b2ca018abe66d5a9f8b4db614c6f.ViewOtherLocationOnMapActivity: +947ms
    04-01 16:40:25.372 E/NetlinkEvent(  299): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
    04-01 16:40:25.612 I/b       (20730): Received API Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    04-01 16:40:25.612 I/c       (20730): Scheduling next attempt in 431700 seconds.
    04-01 16:40:25.615 I/d       (20730): Saved auth token
    04-01 16:40:25.719 I/SFPerfTracer(  258):      triggers: (rate: 7:437) (compose: 1:20) (post: 0:21) (render: 2:51) (6:7515 frames) (7:10501)
    04-01 16:40:25.719 D/SFPerfTracer(  258):        layers: (3:12) (FocusedStackFrame (0xb782cb78): 0:383)* (DimLayer (0xb786b8f0): 0:2)* (StrictModeFlash (0xb7804b60): 0:50)* (StatusBar (0xb780a350): 0:2953) (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper (0xb781e148): 0:163)* (NavigationBar (0xb78a5528): 0:402) (DimLayer (0xb7892338): 1:14)* (asked.askeduniversalremote/md5d1d3b2ca018abe66d5a9f8b4db614c6f.WaitTimeActivity (0xb789fa28): 0:51)- (asked.askeduniversalremote/md5d1d3b2ca018abe66d5a9f8b4db614c6f.ViewOtherSitesActivity (0xb78aef90): 0:108)- (asked.askeduniversalremote/md5d1d3b2ca018abe66d5a9f8b4db614c6f.ViewOtherLocationOnMapActivity (0xb789f9e0): 7:25) 
    04-01 16:40:27.516 D/audio_hw_primary(  303): out_standby: enter: stream (0xb7690308) usecase(1: low-latency-playback)04-01 16:40:27.516 D/audio_hw_primary(  303): out_standby: enter: stream (0xb7690308) usecase(1: low-latency-playback)
    04-01 16:40:27.616 D/hardware_info(  303): hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker04-01 16:40:27.616 D/hardware_info(  303): hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
    04-01 16:40:29.766 E/NEW_BHD (20866): Cannot run on production devices!
    04-01 16:40:31.127 D/Mono    (20730): [0x9e1ff930] worker finishing
    04-01 16:40:31.167 D/WifiStateMachine( 2225): starting scan for 
    04-01 16:40:34.778 D/SLPC    ( 3416): slpc_poll_loop(): handled 1
    04-01 16:40:34.778 D/SLPC    ( 3416): slpc_poll_handle_event(): transition
    04-01 16:40:34.778 D/SLPC    ( 3416): slpc_poll_loop(): about to poll...
    04-01 16:40:34.778 D/sensorhub( 3416): sensorhub_poll() polling...
    04-01 16:40:34.796 E/NEW_BHD (20867): Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
    04-01 16:40:34.797 E/NEW_BHD (20867): Cannot run on production devices!
    04-01 16:40:35.292 D/NetlinkSocketObserver( 2225): NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=6311820, 192.168.105.1, [C86C870B13EB], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_STALE}
    04-01 16:40:35.783 V/AlarmManager( 2225): sending alarm {58361af type 2 *walarm*:com.motorola.slpc.ALARM_STOWED}
    04-01 16:40:35.786 D/ModalityService( 3416): StowedListener(): callback onStowedChange() -> 2
    04-01 16:40:35.787 V/AlarmManager( 2225): done {58361af, *walarm*:com.motorola.slpc.ALARM_STOWED} [4ms]
    04-01 16:40:35.787 D/ModalityManager( 5416): onStowedChange() -> 2, package: com.motorola.actions
```

**UPDATE**
Logcat is now showing the following warning

```
 04-04 09:30:07.355 W/ctxmgr  ( 4204): [AclManager]checkPermissionTypeStatus: no inject permission for { uid=10019, packageName=com.google.android.gms }. Returned permission was: PACKAGE_NOT_WHITELISTED for context name=POWER_CONNECTION, account=account#-517948760#
 04-04 09:30:07.358 W/ctxmgr  ( 4204): [AclManager]checkPermissionTypeStatus: no inject permission for { uid=10019, packageName=com.google.android.gms }. Returned permission was: PACKAGE_NOT_WHITELISTED for context name=POWER_CONNECTION, account=account#-517948760#
```

Comment: What does your `adb logcat` say when you run your application?

Comment: It received the key just fine.  I removed the key from the logcat but no errors I can see.

Comment: Is your mapFrag.Map null?

Comment: No it's not.  map and mapFrag values are not null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the hash provided to your Google API console is the correct one, you can provide two hashes, one for your debug.keystore and one for the production keystore.

to check if the hash is correct, run your app with the debug/production keystore check the log output of this snippet (It's in Java but I believe there are similar APIs in Xamarin) and compare it to the one in the API console:

```
PackageInfo info;
try {
    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.you.name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
        Log.e("hash key", something);
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: You nailed it this helped me find the problem thank you @Mina you rock.

Comment: PS I'll have to wait 18 hours to reward you!.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad that helped

Answer (score 2):

***Here is the c# Implementation***

```
 private void CheckSignatureHash()
  {
   try
     {
                PackageInfo info = PackageManager.GetPackageInfo("com.package.name", PackageInfoFlags.Signatures);
                string hash = "";
                foreach (var sign in info.Signatures)
                {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.GetInstance("SHA");
                    md.Update(sign.ToByteArray());
                    hash += Base64.EncodeToString(md.Digest(), Base64Flags.Default);
                    Console.WriteLine("***********************************");
                    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
                    Console.WriteLine("KeyHash:" + hash);
                    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
                    Console.WriteLine("***********************************");
                }

                //Toast.MakeText(this, hash, ToastLength.Short).Show();
     }
   catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
     {
     }
  catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Inside `<application>` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I had added this but to no avail.  Thank you very much though!

Comment: @yams if you haven't added that it wouldn't work too :)